# pgAdmin4 upgrade to 6.9 issue

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

Previously, I had pgAdmin4 version 5.2 installed on my machine and today I installed version 6.9 of pgAdmin4 after downloading it from website. It got installed properly without error but latest version application is not opening up on my machine. Following is the error information I get after splash screen goes away :

What do I need to do now to make pgadmin4 functional on my machine after new installation? I have tried everything right from clean install to restarting machine several times.

```
**The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:**

pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\krunal.chavda\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\krunal.chavda\AppData\Roaming
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: UAT
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_9684_FNBCYQROPXZWTXDR
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: KA-LPT-261
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\krunal.chavda
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\krunal.chavda\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\HYD
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\krunal.chavda\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\krunal.chavda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\krunal.chavda\.dotnet\tools
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 9ec3f2f5-adc6-4cc9-a719-26e01ab7ed2f
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 5050
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 4e03
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\KRUNAL~1.CHA\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\KRUNAL~1.CHA\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDNSDOMAIN: MDC.ANBLICKS.COM
  - USERDOMAIN: MDC
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: MDC
  - USERNAME: krunal.chavda
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\krunal.chavda
  - windir: C:\Windows
  - ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: 1
  - __COMPAT_LAYER: Installer
--------------------------------------------------------

2022-05-27 16:15:38,075: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off

2022-05-27 16:15:39,270: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:40,258: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:41,331: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:42,272: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:43,286: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:44,270: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:45,269: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:46,287: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1570, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    self.ensure_sync(func)()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\__init__.py", line 55, in create_module_preference
    self.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 330, in register_preferences
    ServerType.register_preferences()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 124, in register_preferences
    paths.migrate_user_preferences(st.utility_path.pid,
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\utils\preferences.py", line 656, in migrate_user_preferences
    pref.value = converter_func(pref.value)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\types.py", line 108, in path_converter
    {item['version']: item for item in json.loads(old_path)}
  File "json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    
  File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

2022-05-27 16:15:47,269: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows:

- uninstall previous version
- remove C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\pgadmin directory
- remove C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\pgadmin4 directory
- remove **C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin directory**
- install new version